# Bounding the order of a group by its nilpotentizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-nilpotent group. We put $nil_G(x)=\{y\in G\mid \langle x,y \rangle \text{ is nilpotent}\}$, called the nilpotentizer of $x$. Note that $nil_G(x)$ may not be a subgroup of $G$, for example in $S_4$, $|nil_{S_4}((12)(34))|=16$. Suppose $|G\setminus nil_G(x)|=n$ for some $x\in G$, then can we find an upper bound for $|G|$ depending on $n$? (The motivation of this question come from the fact that if $|G\setminus C_G(x)|=m$, then $|G|\leq 3m/2$.)Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would guess that the answer is yes, but the nilpotentizer can comprise an arbtrarily high proportion of the group elements, so there will not be a linear bound on $|G|$ in terms of $n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have observe that for any finite non-nilpotent group $G$, $|nil_G(x)|\leq 3|G|/4$, for any non-hypercenter element $x\in G$. So I have tried to show that if there exist a non-hypercenter element $x\in G$, such that $3|G|/4 < |nil_G(x)|<|G|$, then $G$ is nilpotent. But I could not succeed in doing so. If I am able to do so, then $|G|\leq 7|G|/4$.

Comment: I think that $|G| \le 7|G|/4$ is true in any case???!!!

Comment: As I said before, for any $k<1$, there are examples of groups $G$ and $x \in G$ with $k|G| < |{\rm nil}_G(x)| < |G|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, you are right. My last comment is not so useful. What I want to say is that $|nil_G(x)|\leq 3|G|/4$ for any non-hypercenter element $x$ of any finite non-nilpotent group $G$. But what you observe is that, there is group $G$ and an element $x$ such that $3|G|/4<|nil_G(x)|<|G|$(in fact you have observe that it is true for more general cases). This is very interesting. This means that my observation is wrong. I would like to know such group and such element $x$(since you have already have one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer to the question. I find it hard to believe that for any fixed $n>1$ there could be groups $G$ of arbitrarily large order and $x \in G$ with $|G \setminus {\rm nil}_G(x)| = n$, so I am guessing that the answer is yes there is a bound, but I don't know how to go about proving it.

Here I am just describing examples that show that there can be no such linear bound. The idea is to construct groups with a similar shape to $S_4$ but with the prime $2$ replaced by an arbitrary prime $p$, to construct groups $G$ and $x \in G$ with $|G| > |{\rm nil}_G(x)| > (p-1)|G|/p$.

Let $p$ be any prime and $H$ a Frobenius group with kernel $K$ and complement of order $p$. Now let $G$ be any group with a elementary abelian normal $p$-subgroup $N$ with $G/N \cong H$ such that $N$ is not central in the inverse image of $K$ in $G$, and let $x \in N$ such that $x$ is not centralized by $K$. So, there exists $y \in G$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle$ is not nilpotent, and hence ${\rm nil}_G(x) \ne G$. For example we could take $G$ to be the wreath product of a cyclic group of order $p$ with $H$.

Then, since all element of $H \setminus K$ have order $p$, an element of $G$ lies in ${\rm nil}_G(x)$ whenever its image in $H$ does not lie in $K \setminus \{1\}$, and the proportion of such elements is 
$$\frac{|K|(p-1)-1}{|K|p} > \frac{p-1}{p}.$$

Comment: This is a nice observation. Thank you